# .htaccess disallow trailing slash on re-written URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm re-writing some of my URLs using the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^register/?$ register.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^logout/?$ logout.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ game.php?game=$1 [NC,L]
```

And it works great when you visit /login or /register or anything, but when you add a trailing slash, it's missing the stylesheet. I've tried adding a base link in the head, but that messes up more than it fixes (makes things think they're coming from an external URL).

I have tried this code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

But it takes you to my http://www.example.com/login, instead of say http://www.example.com/directory/another/login (where the files are all located).

Is there an easy way to just remove trailing slashes?

Comment: Is this .htaccess located in `/directory/another/`?

Comment: _The_ problem with what you tried, is that leading `/`.  That's what takes you to the top.  I suspect it'll work fine if you just drop it: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a `RewriteBase` for the sub-directory this .htaccess is residing in and tweak your trailing slash rule accordingly:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /directory/another/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ $1 [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteRule ^(login|register|logout)/?$ login.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ game.php?game=$1 [NC,L]
```